# Creating a common ancestor form in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, refactoring, visual-studio, winforms

I have 5 forms which in hindsight should have an ancestor descended from Form.  Unfortunately, the common elements of the forms is a splitContainer and a listbox in one of the containers.  Each form has it's own collection of panels in the other half of the splitter.

Is there any way to fix this problem without having to basically recreate the forms from scratch?  I have had zero luck trying to change paternity with ^x^v.

Comment: You should have refactored when you baked up the second form and it ended up too similar to the first one. Now, you stacked up some technical debt against yourself. Good luck...

Comment: With 5 forms, how bad could starting from scratch be? You can copy and paste the parts you want to keep/reintroduce into your new forms.

Comment: @MartinMaat But you can't copy/paste controls onto a new parent.

Comment: What are we talking about? WPF or Windows Forms?

Comment: @MartinMaat Forms.

Comment: Can you copy one of your current forms (the two code files, renaming the copies to your ancestor) and the delete everything not to be part of the parent? Then change the ancestor of original forms and delete everything that is now covered by ancestor?

Comment: @MartinMaat Moving the code is no big deal.  Moving the components is where it gets ugly.